# Unable to override TextBlock Style in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, propertygrid, templatebinding

I have this in the ResourceDictionary, defining a style on application level:

```
<Style x:Key="TextBlockStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,10,0,10"/>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}" />
```

I want to remove the Margins for a particular TextBlock, which is inside the xctk:PropertyGrid control (from the Extended WPF Toolkit). If i just change the numbers in the ResourceDictionary style above, it works.

Now I'm trying to override the PropertyGrid's style in the specific window XAML instead of the global styles.

```
<xctk:PropertyGrid>
    <xctk:PropertyGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
        </Style>
    </xctk:PropertyGrid.Resources>
</xctk:PropertyGrid>
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work, the TextBlock in the PropertyGrid is unchanged, keeping the global style.

UPDATED:

The xtck:PropertyGrid has an xctk:WatermarkTextBox inside it. The WatermarkTextBox has this inside:

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_WatermarkHost" Content="{TemplateBinding Watermark}"
    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding WatermarkTemplate}"
    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
    isHitTestVisible="False"
    Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
    Visibility="Collapsed" />
```

It is this ContentPresenter, which apparently produces the TextBlock in question.

1. The style in the ResourceDictionary gets applied to it, changing the margin.
2. But my style inside  doesn't override it.

How would I do that?

Comment: I don't see TextBlock in the PropertyGrid, could you please provide this code?

Comment: I've updated the original question.

Answer (score 1):

I've just performed a number of tests and I simply can't reproduce your problem. Any `Style` that I put into the `UIElement.Resources` section works just the same as a `Style` that I put into the `App.Resources` section.

If a `UIElement` has a property set either directly, or in its own `UIElement.Style`, then trying to set that same property to a different value in another `Style` just won't work. This is true regardless of where that `Style` is defined.

Are you *really* sure that changing the `Margin` values in your `App.Resources` section *actually* makes a difference? Try setting the `Background` property to red or something else that you can be 100% sure of.

Incidentally, you *might* know this already, but if you want to set a `Margin` property with four identical values, you can just set it with just one value like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="Something" Margin="0" />
```

UPDATE >>>

@Andrew, look at the XAML you added... I think *there* is your answer... look at the following line:

```
Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
```

The `Margin` property is actually set from the `Padding` value of the template parent, so try setting the `Padding` property instead. That *should* link through to the `TextBox.Margin`.

Comment: I was under the impression:
1. a TargetType="TextBlock" style in App.Resources is kind of a "global style"
2. a TargetType="TextBlock" style in a specific UIElement.Resources (for example Window.Resources) is a more targeted style, which would override the global style in any of the elements contained within

Comment: Playing around with background was a good idea, and the results are pretty interesting. Both styles target TextBlock, yet different fields get colored if I set the color in Window.Resources vs in App.Resources.

Comment: Your first comment is correct. The Framework will first look for `Resources` in the local `UIElement.Resources` section, then those of any parent controls, then the `Window.Resources` and then the `Application.Resources` section. Setting a local value will 'override' (for lack of a better word) those set further away. Your second comment is indeed strange... or the situation is strange.

Comment: Perhaps you can target that `TextBlock` using code, eg. walking the visual tree: See [Understanding the Visual Tree and Logical Tree in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21495/Understanding-the-Visual-Tree-and-Logical-Tree-in) for help on this.

Comment: I updated my original question, could you look at it please? As I can see, it's a ContentPresenter producing a TextBlock, and its Margin comes from TemplateBinding.

Comment: Tried it, it doesn't help: 
`<xctk:PropertyGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />                    
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.Margin" Value="0" />
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.Padding" Value="0" />
                </Style>
            </xctk:PropertyGrid.Resources>`